# how do i cast the return value from dlsym properly for function with const types?

Tags: c++, dlsym

I want to retrieve a function pointer with `dlsym` which has `const char*`s in its prototype. How can I get this done properly, I tried:

```
int main (void)
{
    void *alprhandle = NULL;
    std::string alprlib = "/usr/lib/libalpropencv.so.3";
#ifdef DLSYM
    void*(*palpr_init)(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*);
    int (*palpr_is_loaded)(void*);
    alpr::AlprResults (*palpr_recognize)(std::vector<char>);

    //open OpenALPR OpenCV library
    alprhandle = dlopen(alprlib.c_str(), RTLD_NOW);
    if (!alprhandle){
        std::cerr << dlerror() << alprlib <<std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    //find the address of functions
    palpr_init = (const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*)dlsym(alprhandle, "openalpr_init");
    if (!palpr_init)
```

But the compiler tells me
`error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’` by the line with the call to `dlsym()`

**EDIT1**

```
typedef void*(*palpr_init_type)(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*);
        void*(*palpr_init)     (const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*);
typedef int (*palpr_is_loaded_type)(void*);
        int (*palpr_is_loaded)     (void*);
typedef alpr::AlprResults (*palpr_recognize_type)(std::vector<char>);
        alpr::AlprResults (*palpr_recognize)     (std::vector<char>);

//open OpenALPR OpenCV library
alprhandle = dlopen(alprlib.c_str(), RTLD_NOW);
if (!alprhandle){
    std::cerr << dlerror() << alprlib <<std::endl;
    exit(0);
}
//find the address of functions
palpr_init = (palpr_init_type)dlsym(alprhandle, "openalpr_init");
if (!palpr_init)
    std::cerr << "FATAL: Could not find openalpr_init " << dlerror() << std::endl;
palpr_is_loaded = (palpr_is_loaded_type)dlsym(alprhandle, "openalpr_is_loaded");
if (!palpr_is_loaded)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef void* (*palpr_init_type)(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*);
palpr_init_type palpr_init = (palpr_init_type)dlsym(...)
```

Comment: and what if my function returns an `int` instead of `void*`? Following your typedef method, I get `cannot convert ‘int (**)(void*)’ to ‘int (*)(void*)’ in assignment`

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Show the code that produces the error.

Comment: See **EDIT1** above, `palpr_is_loaded` ius the function in question

Comment: [Compiles for me](http://rextester.com/YQO73396). The code you show is not the same code you actually compile.

Answer (score 0):

When using function pointers the best thing to do is declare a `typedef` for the type, then you only have to type it once, its easier to change and is usable in casts.

For example with typedefs your code becomes:

```
typedef void*(*palpr_init_t)(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*);
typedef int (*palpr_is_loaded_t)(void*);
alpr::AlprResults (*palpr_recognize_t)(std::vector<char>);

int main (void)
{
    void *alprhandle = NULL;
    std::string alprlib = "/usr/lib/libalpropencv.so.3";
#ifdef DLSYM
    palpr_init_t palpr_init;
    palpr_is_loaded_t palpr_is_loaded;
    palpr_recognize_t palpr_recognize;

    //open OpenALPR OpenCV library
    alprhandle = dlopen(alprlib.c_str(), RTLD_NOW);
    if (!alprhandle){
        std::cerr << dlerror() << alprlib <<std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    //find the address of functions
    palpr_init = (palpr_init_t)dlsym(alprhandle, "openalpr_init");
    if (!palpr_init)
```